# Angular 9 - Sharing Data Between Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, caching, routes

I'd like to share data between routes, instead of getting it from the API on each component load.

**Repo**: https://github.com/theADAMJR/2PG-Dashboard

Currently when a user loads a /dashboard/:id/... route, this is called:

```
this.roles = await this.guildService.getRoles(this.guildId);
```

I'd only like this to be called **once** when a user loads any dashboard route: **/dashboard/:id/...**.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. In its simplest form, you can just append your `data` to the routes `state` object:

```
this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], {state: {data: {...}}});
```

https://angular.io/guide/router

You could also do:

- Resolvers (https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)
- Implement proper state management (https://ngrx.io/)
- Create a Singleton Service to act as your global in-app storage
- Use LocalStorage (not recommended, but you can do it)